# Character will do a small jump before doing a full-sized jump in JS

Tags: javascript, css, game-physics, game-development

I am building a platforming game in JavaScript.
For some reason, when my character lands on a platform, the character will then begin alternating between doing a very small jump, and then do a full-sized jump. I want it to do a full-sized jump every time. Why isn't this working? 
Here's my code:

```
if (isCollideY(platforms[i].getBoundingClientRect(), document.getElementById('spriteNotReal').getBoundingClientRect()) == true) {
                if (falling == true && (jumping == false)) {
                            moveY = platforms[i].getBoundingClientRect().y + 3;
                            momentumY = 0;
                            onSolidGround = true;
                        }
            }
```

```
if (event.code == 'KeyW' && (onSolidGround == true)) { 
            momentumY = momentumY + 20;
            onSolidGround = false;
            falling = false;
            jumping = true;
        }
```

```
else if (onSolidGround == false) {
        if (momentumY < 0) {
            falling = true;
        }
        else if (momentumY > 0) {
            jumping = true;
        }
        else {
            jumping = false;
        }
        moveX += momentumX / 3 + 1;
        document.getElementById("spriteNotReal").src = "jumpmain.gif";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue with your booleans for jumping / falling / onSolidGround. Most likely the character is somehow being flagged as something other than

```
onSolidGround = true;
jumping = false;
falling = false;
```

When the first jump is taking place.

Comment: How do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Make cases for each state of being and what the values should be at that state. Set each Boolean value according to what it should be. Reconsider what each transition to each state is and if it makes sense.